# Why do FileType autocommands not appear to work when using multiple filetypes?

Tags: filetype, ftplugin

> Not everyone considers setting `b:undo_ftplugin` to be a "best practice" the
>   way I do, but as far as I can tell, the behavior described in this question
>   depends on it being set as part of the autocommand. This isn't an unreasonable
>   thing to do, particularly if one religiously sets it, like I do.

I've been working on a plugin (call it `foo`) that uses multiple filetypes to
enhance the editing experience of files in a particular path while still
leveraging all the goodies that are setup by their respective filetype plugins.

More concretely, the plugin sets the filetype of any file in this path to
`foo.original_filetype`. Vim's filetype plugin mechanism will use filetype
plugins (and filetype autocommands) for both the `foo` and `original_filetype`
filetypes in this case:

> When a dot appears in the value then this separates two filetype
>   names.
>
> Example: `/* vim: set filetype=c.doxygen : */`
>
> This will use the "c" filetype first, then the "doxygen" filetype.
>   This works both for filetype plugins and for syntax files.  More than
>   one dot may appear.
>
> -- `:help 'filetype'`

Now, I ran into a bizarre situation while experimenting with this plugin. For
reasons™, I was keeping some extra `foo` filetype settings separate from my
usual config, so I had done something like this:

```
" in a personal file sourced at the top of my vimrc
augroup FooStuff
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType *foo* nnoremap <buffer> f :echo "foo!"<CR>
  autocmd FileType *foo* let b:undo_ftplugin = 'nunmap <buffer> f'
augroup END
```

(Matching `*foo*` is necessary, since the entire dotted-filetype is matched
against.)

Now, if I enter vim and `:set filetype=foo.markdown`, and then `:map <buffer>`,
I get

```
n  \u3         *@:call UnderlineHeading(3)<CR>
n  \u2         *@:call UnderlineHeading(2)<CR>
n  \u1         *@:call UnderlineHeading(1)<CR>
n  \o          *@:silent !open %<CR>:redraw!<CR>
o  i#3         *@:<C-U>execute "normal! ?^###\\s.?e\r\rvg_"<CR>
o  i#2         *@:<C-U>execute "normal! ?^##\\s.?e\r\rvg_"<CR>
o  i#1         *@:<C-U>execute "normal! ?^#\\s.?e\r\rvg_"<CR>
o  ih-         *@:<C-U>execute "normal! ?^--\\+$\r\rkvg_"<CR>
o  ih=         *@:<C-U>execute "normal! ?^==\\+$\r\rkvg_"<CR>
```

Those are all markdown mappings, and `f` is conspicuously absent. What gives?

Comment: Do you really have use cases where you change the type of the current buffer? (I must admit that I define so many things in my C++ ftplugins, and as I have no ft-changing use case, that I've never took the time to set `b:undo_ftplugin`)

Comment: @LucHermitte happens all the time when I’m experimenting, yeah. Plus, for this plugin, what if someone wants to remove the “extra” filetype for a particular file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, there is a subtle interaction between `FileType` events and the
actual `ftplugin` mechanism.

When the filetype is *changed*, all matching `FileType` events are run. As near
as I can tell, this is one of the first things to be done.

So the current "state" would include both the buffer-local mapping *and* the
`b:undo_ftplugin` necessary to undo it. This will be relevant for the next step.

When vim has `filetype plugin on`, it uses `ftplugin.vim` in `runtimepath` to
set up the following autocommand:

```
augroup filetypeplugin
  au FileType * call s:LoadFTPlugin()

  func! s:LoadFTPlugin()
    if exists("b:undo_ftplugin")
      exe b:undo_ftplugin
      unlet! b:undo_ftplugin b:did_ftplugin
    endif

    let s = expand("<amatch>")
    if s != ""
      if &cpo =~# "S" && exists("b:did_ftplugin")
    " In compatible mode options are reset to the global values, need to
    " set the local values also when a plugin was already used.
    unlet b:did_ftplugin
      endif

      " When there is a dot it is used to separate filetype names.  Thus for
      " "aaa.bbb" load "aaa" and then "bbb".
      for name in split(s, '\.')
    exe 'runtime! ftplugin/' . name . '.vim ftplugin/' . name . '_*.vim ftplugin/' . name . '/*.vim'
      endfor
    endif
  endfunc
augroup END
```

The important thing here is that the function that loads all the filetype plugin
files (like the one for markdown in the example) will start by undoing settings
using `b:undo_ftplugin`. As you have no doubt realized, this undoes the mapping
setup in the first autocommand.

While you *could* not set `b:undo_ftplugin` in the first autocommand to fix
this, that feels dirty if you already like to set it. Instead, things will work
just fine if you put your settings in a proper `ftplugin` file (as I have
recommended in numerous places on this site; shame on me for not taking my own
advice).